upload image with React using Laravel
I'm beginner
I try to upload an image.jpg with React using Laravel ,
it work with Postman but with React js dose not work and throws a message error : FormToAddFile.jsx:17
   POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/storefile 422 (Unprocessable Content)

here is my codes :
React form :
import React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react"
import axiosClient from "../../../axios-client";

export default function FormToAddFile(){
    const fileValue=useRef();
    const nameValue=useRef();
    const descriptionValue=useRef();

    const SaveFile=()=>{
      
        const payload={
            image:fileValue.current.value,
            name:nameValue.current.value,
            description:descriptionValue.current.value,
        }
        console.log("tosave",payload)
        axiosClient.post("/storefile",payload,{headers:{'Content-Type':"multipart/form-data"}},).then(({data})=>{
            console.log(data)
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
    return (

        <div className="w-fit mt-4">
            <form action="" className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 overflow-x-hidden "  >
                <input ref={nameValue} type="text" placeholder="File Name" className="py-2 pl-2 focus:outline-none text-black font-semibold"/>
               
                <textarea ref={descriptionValue} placeholder="Description" name="" id="" className="resize-none py-2 pl-2 focus:outline-none text-black font-semibold"></textarea>
                <label htmlFor="inputfile " className="bg-cyan-600">
                    <input ref={fileValue} id="inputfile" type="file" className="savefilelabel" />
                </label>
                <button onClick={SaveFile} className="savefile">Save File</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

my controller:
public function store(FilesStoreRequest $request)
    {
        try {
            $imageName = Str::random(32).".".$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
      
            // Create Product
            File::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'image' => $imageName,
                'description' => $request->description
            ]);
      
            // Save Image in Storage folder
            Storage::disk('public')->put($imageName, file_get_contents($request->image));
      
            // Return Json Response
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "Product successfully created."
            ],200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Return Json Response
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "Something went really wrong!"
            ],500);
        }
    }

**it's working with Postman but not with my React form **

People Please use inertia it is best way to deal with laravel communication

The reason is that you used general json data. To upload file, you must use FormData object because the backend expects a multipart/form-data. I will provide updated code.
import React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react"
import axiosClient from "../../../axios-client";

export default function FormToAddFile(){
    const fileValue=useRef();
    const nameValue=useRef();
    const descriptionValue=useRef();

    const SaveFile=()=>{
        // Create FormData object and append necessary information.
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', fileValue.current.files[0]);
        formData.append('name', nameValue.current.value);
        formData.append('description', descriptionValue.current.value);
        
        console.log("tosave", formData);
    
        axiosClient.post("/storefile", formData, {headers:{'Content-Type':"multipart/form-data"}},).then(({data})=>{
            console.log(data)
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
    return (

        <div className="w-fit mt-4">
            <form action="" className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 overflow-x-hidden "  >
                <input ref={nameValue} type="text" placeholder="File Name" className="py-2 pl-2 focus:outline-none text-black font-semibold"/>
               
                <textarea ref={descriptionValue} placeholder="Description" name="" id="" className="resize-none py-2 pl-2 focus:outline-none text-black font-semibold"></textarea>
                <label htmlFor="inputfile " className="bg-cyan-600">
                    <input ref={fileValue} id="inputfile" type="file" className="savefilelabel" />
                </label>
                <button onClick={SaveFile} className="savefile">Save File</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}


great thank you sir
